# Starting SublimeREPL with hotkey

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, read-eval-print-loop, sublimerepl

How to add a hotkey for starting `SublimeREPL` for Python from `SublimeREPL` Package. You can start it from Command Palette by typing it, but I would like to assign it to key, lets say to `f2`.

This is what I have so far:

```
{ "keys": ["f2"], "command": "repl_open" ,"cmd": ["python", "-i", "-u"], 
"cwd": "$file_path", "encoding": "utf8", "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},
 "external_id": "python", "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage", "type": "subprocess"} ,
```

But in console I can see this error:

```
TypeError: run() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'encoding' and 'type'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments for the `repl_open` command need to be in an `args` dict:

```json
    { 
        "keys": ["f2"],
        "command": "repl_open" ,
        "args": { 
            "cmd": ["python", "-i", "-u"], 
            "cwd": "$file_path", 
            "encoding": "utf8", 
            "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},
            "external_id": "python", 
            "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.sublime-syntax", 
            "type": "subprocess"
        }
    },
```

I also changed the name of the syntax to reflect its new name.